# Why Adt plugin for eclipse doesnot work?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt

I am running windows and eclipse mars. I downloaded and installed the [ADT plugin](https://developer.android.com/studio/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html) version 23.0.7. but nothing happens after I install it. I can't find the option to create a new android project. Also there is no option to convert a java project(this is actualy adt project before i uninstal and update adt) into an android project.

Comment: The ADT plugin is no longer supported.

Comment: so... what should i do now ? my pc cant run android studio...

Comment: "my pc cant run android studio" -- why not?

Comment: @CommonsWare everything work well before i update adt. btw where i can download andmore plugin for eclipse. i cant download it via eclipse marketplace

Comment: android studio too heavy in my pc. my pc have only 2 gb ram

Comment: IMHO, Eclipse will not run well in 2GB either.

Comment: eclipse just take 800MB while android studio took more than 1 gb

Comment: or there may be a trick to make android studio run faster?

Answer (score 0):

Open the Error Log view after installing ADT and see if there are any relevant errors reported there.

Also, since ADT is no longer supported, it may just be incompatible with Eclipse's Mars (and newer) releases. Try installing it into [Eclipse Luna](https://eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/luna/sr2).